# Showing the last item of a list in a ChoiceField

Tags: python, key-value, choicefield

This code is showing only the last item of a list of dictionaries:

```
def chooseOneServer():
    dara = websvc()
    i=0
    for item in dara:
        for key,value in item.items() :
            if key == '1' :
                servers = ( ('i',value), ) 
                i +=1  
    return servers
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've already answered this in the comments of your last question, but here it is again:

```
def chooseOneServer():
    dara = websvc()
    i=0
    servers = []
    for item in dara:
        for key,value in item.items() :
            if key == '1':
                servers.append(('i',value))
                i += 1
    return servers
```

You just add each item to a list, rather than overwriting the same tuple each time.